# How to imagine (visualize) the difference between LARS and Lasso

Tags: lasso, lars

I'm reading [the LARS paper](http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/LARS/LeastAngle_2002.pdf). It turns out the solution path of LARS is quite similar with Lasso, and that paper has an explanation in section `3.1`. An important fact is that for Lasso solution $\hat\beta$ subject to $\hat{\pmb{\mu}}={\bf{X}}\hat\beta$, the sign of any non-zero coordinate $\hat\beta_j$ must agree with the sign of the relevant correlation $\hat{c_j}={\bf{x}}_j^T({\bf{y}}-\hat{\pmb{\mu}})$, and LARS doesn't have that restriction. For LARS, the sign of $\hat\beta_j$ may change. The reason is given in the same section in the paper, and it's not too difficult to understand algebraically.

My question is how to understand this fact in a geometric way. As mentioned in that paper, for LARS, at each stage the estimator $\hat{\pmb{\mu}}_k$ approaches, but does not reach, the projection of $\bf{y}$ onto the subspace spanned by the active set. The path makes a bend (adds one dimension) at each stage to a higher-dimension projection. But I cannot imagine the sign of any coefficient $\hat\beta_j$ will change on the way. I failed to construct a 3-dim example.